# Populate/Join multiple tables of many to many relationship table in mysql

Tags: mysql, join

This question should have been asked before, but I am finding it hard to find.
I have table `users`,`allergies`,`dietaries`. users can have multiple allergies,and multiple dietaries. So for that I have `user_allergies`, `user_dietaries` table which store both tables foreign key.

Now I want to show list of users with their corresponding allergies, dietaries name. I tried with left join like this -->

```
SELECT
    users.user_id as 'id',
    IFNULL(CONCAT(users.first_name,' ',users.last_name),'') as 'name',
    IFNULL(GROUP_CONCAT(allergies.title),'') as 'allergies'
FROM (users
    LEFT JOIN user_allergies
        ON users.user_id = user_allergies.user_id
    LEFT JOIN allergies
        ON user_allergies.allergies_id = allergies.allergies_id
      )
GROUP BY users.user_id;
```

Which respond exactly like I want-->

```
7 | Khabib Nurmagamedov | Milk,Corn
8 | Conor Mcgregor      | Milk,Corn
```

Now I wish to get the `dietaries` same way. So I added Left Join for dietaries similarly -->

```
SELECT
    users.user_id as 'id',
    IFNULL(CONCAT(users.first_name,' ',users.last_name),'') as 'name',
    IFNULL(GROUP_CONCAT(allergies.title),'') as 'allergies',
    IFNULL(GROUP_CONCAT(dietaries.title),'') as 'dietaries'
FROM (users
    LEFT JOIN user_allergies
        ON users.user_id = user_allergies.user_id
    LEFT JOIN allergies
        ON user_allergies.allergies_id = allergies.allergies_id
    LEFT JOIN user_dietaries
        ON users.user_id = user_dietaries.user_id
    LEFT JOIN dietaries
        ON user_allergies.allergies_id = dietaries.dietaries_id
      )  
GROUP BY users.user_id;
```

But now the output I get -->

```
7 | Khabib Nurmagamedov | Milk,Corn,Eggs,Meat | Milk,Corn,Eggs,Meat
8 | Conor Mcgregor      | Milk,Corn,Eggs,Meat | Milk,Corn,Eggs,Meat
```

Which should be -->

```
7 | Khabib Nurmagamedov | Milk,Corn | Eggs,Meat
8 | Conor Mcgregor      | Milk,Corn | Eggs,Meat
```

I am struggling here. What should I do?
Thanks In Advance.

**Edit:**
Te response is -->

```
7 | Khabib Nurmagamedov | Milk,Corn,Milk,Corn | Milk,Milk,Corn,Corn
8 | Conor Mcgregor      | Milk,Eggs,Milk,Eggs | Milk,Milk,Corn,Corn
```

I thought both table data getting concatenated but apparently result is appearing twice. 
Result needs to be-->

```
7 | Khabib Nurmagamedov | Milk,Corn | Milk,Corn
8 | Conor Mcgregor      | Milk,Eggs | Milk,Corn
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding Distinct before allergies.title and dietaries.title, I can get my desired result.
But not sure why title fields were appearing twice.

```
SELECT
    users.user_id as 'id',
    IFNULL(CONCAT(users.first_name,' ',users.last_name),'') as 'name',
    IFNULL(GROUP_CONCAT(Distinct allergies.title),'') as 'allergies',
    IFNULL(GROUP_CONCAT(Distinct dietaries.title),'') as 'dietaries'
FROM (users
    LEFT JOIN user_allergies
        ON users.user_id = user_allergies.user_id
    LEFT JOIN allergies
        ON user_allergies.allergies_id = allergies.allergies_id
    LEFT JOIN user_dietaries
        ON users.user_id = user_dietaries.user_id
    LEFT JOIN dietaries
        ON user_allergies.allergies_id = dietaries.dietaries_id
      )  
GROUP BY users.user_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you want your GROUP_CONCAT in 2 separate columns, and it can't work like that.

You have to join your group_concat results 2 times, from the user table:

```
SELECT u.user_id as 'id',
             IFNULL(CONCAT(u.first_name,' ',u.last_name),'') as 'name',
             ua.allergies_c as 'allergies',
             ud.dietaries_c as 'dietaries'
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            users.user_id ,
            IFNULL(GROUP_CONCAT(allergies.title),'') as allergies_c
        FROM (users
            LEFT JOIN user_allergies
                ON users.user_id = user_allergies.user_id
            LEFT JOIN allergies
                ON user_allergies.allergies_id = allergies.allergies_id
              )
        GROUP BY users.user_id
    ) ua ON u.user_id=ua.user_id
LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            users.user_id,
            IFNULL(GROUP_CONCAT(dietaries.title),'') as dietaries_c
        FROM (users
            LEFT JOIN user_dietaries
                ON users.user_id = user_dietaries.user_id
            LEFT JOIN dietaries
                ON user_dietaries.dietaries_id = dietaries.dietaries_id
              )
        GROUP BY users.user_id
    ) ud ON u.user_id=ud.user_id
```

I made some mass-replace to go faster, you might have a few things to fix, but the idea is there.

Comment: ua ON and ud on highlights as error in phpmyadmin. Also can you look at my answer above, where by adding distinct I get my desired result. Is that logically correct?

Comment: Its because I forgot to remove the ; in the sub queries

Comment: Yeah, found that. Can you tell me the difference between your answer, and my one above? Both are providing the same answer. I am afraid I have the result using distinct, but it may not be the correct logic as I am limiting the title appearing multiple times using distinct.

Comment: Your approach is wrong because if you come to a situation where some dietaries and allergies have the same name, you'll lose them